# error on MySQL joins with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables I want to join and if `supplierprice.networkname=default` then i don't want to display that. so my query is:

```
SELECT 
    supplierprice.country, 
    supplierprice.networkname, 
    supplierprice.mcc, 
    supplierprice.mnc, 
    `301`.clientprice, 
    client_list.currency
FROM 
    supplierprice 
INNER JOIN 
    `301` 
ON 
   supplierprice.supp_price_id = `301`.net_id
INNER JOIN 
    client_list 
ON 
    `301`.clientid = client_list.clientid  
WHERE 
    supplierprice.networkname <>default 
AND ORDER BY 
    supplierprice.country ASC,supplierprice.networkname ASC
```

I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'and ORDER BY supplierprice.country ASC,supplierprice.networkname
>   ASC LIMIT 0, ' at line 4

can any one help how to fix

Comment: `default` is a MySql keyword. Quote it while using it in your query.

Comment: you have an and clause after remove that and from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**And** should not come between Where and Order By

You can Order like this also

```
ORDER BY supplierprice.country,supplierprice.networkname ASC
```

and If Default is column value then pass it as 'default'

Try this

```
SELECT supplierprice.country, supplierprice.networkname, supplierprice.mcc, supplierprice.mnc, `301`.clientprice, client_list.currency
FROM supplierprice 
INNER JOIN `301` ON supplierprice.supp_price_id = `301`.net_id
INNER JOIN client_list ON `301`.clientid = client_list.clientid  
where supplierprice.networkname <> 'default'
ORDER BY supplierprice.country,supplierprice.networkname ASC
```

> SELECT SYNTAX

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY supplierprice.country,supplierprice.networkname ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Comment: @arok are you using LIMIT

Comment: @arok my guess is about default

Comment: i query i am not using limit

Comment: defult is a column value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48655/discussion-between-arok-and-vignesh-kumar)